# How to make a string variable literal?

Tags: c#, string, path, escaping

You know how you make a string literal or "escaped" with the @ sign right?

`string foo = @"\escaped\string"`

I was searching all over the internet, and I cannot find a way to make a string variable do that. If you are curious why I want to do that, here is a bit of backstory:

I was making a C# addon for my batch script, which would base64 a string and save it in a file. However, I kept getting an error by the name of "Illegal characters in path name" or something among those lines. So naturally, I went away googling and the only "fix" I could find is to @ the string. However, the problem is, I don't have just a simple plain text string variable. I get the location of the executable and then put it into a variable, so I can create the file right where the executable is located (the same folder). And, as I said previously, I cannot do that, because of weird path errors. I tried `String.Replace` and `Regex.Escape` but none of them worked, because it seems like the error is right when I call the function to get the location. For reference, this is the "command" I'm using to get the location of the executable.

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

And yes, I did try other tricks, like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and a bit more but none of them seem to work.

Any way to  solve this? I'm getting really frustrated because this is supposed to be easy...

Comment: I think you are mixing up variables and constants. Escaping (either by double slashes or the @ sign) is only for constants, not for anything that comes from another function call (like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`). Can you show the piece of code that gives you the error?

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` It's just that. In places like C:\Users\...\Desktop\Folder it works, but when there are some special characters like spaces or dots involved it just crashes on me.

Comment: Can you post your complete relevant code?

Comment: Sure, https://hastebin.com/ralufayica.cpp
Line 10 is the problematic guy over there

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you are working on WSL, is that right?

Comment: If by WSL you mean a console application, then yes.

Comment: I mean the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq)

Comment: Uh no, I develop my program in Visual C# Express 2010, and I open it up with cmd

Comment: Also, because the problem is with the path name, I might as well just share the path the program is in:

C:\Users\InxaneNinja\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\base1\base1\bin\Release

Comment: Is this path that you mentioned surrounded by *escaped* double quotes? Because I suspect it is not enjoying the white spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189723/discussion-between-remigiusz-schoida-and-gabriel-lima).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try using the static methods [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2) when working with string/path manipulation.